# Firing 2 Redux Actions , only 1 action is fired

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-form, react-lifecycle

I've fired an action in `componentDidMount` :

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.getQuests();
}
```

and would like to fire another action once it's completed, I've used the lifecycle method `componentWillReceiveProps`

```
componentWillReceiveProps = async nextProps => {
  if (nextProps.questObject.length !== 0) {
    const authToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("authToken");
    this.props.getProfile(authToken);
  }
};
```

However only `this.props.getQuests();` is fired and the 2nd action `this.props.getProfile(authToken)` is not being fired.

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ quest, profile }) => {
  const { error, loading, questObject } = quest;

  const { profileObj } = profile;

  return { error, loading, questObject, profileObj };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getQuests, getProfile }
)(HomeScreen);
```

Currently it returns the following error:

```
Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted 
component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your 
application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in 
the componentWillUnmount method.
```

Comment: Are you using any redux middleware, such as `redux-thunk` or `redux-saga` etc...?

Comment: @SGhaleb I am using redux-thunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to update the DOM before it is mounted.when you are using `componentWillReceiveProps`,make sure you compare the `this.props` and the latest props i.e., `nextProps`.Otherwise,`componentWillReceiveProps` will render the component unnecessarily so that might lead to infinite loop.

```
    componentWillReceiveProps = nextProps => {
      if (this.props.questObject !== nextProps.questObject && 
          nextProps.questObject.length !== 0) {
       try {
             const authToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("authToken");
             this.props.getProfile(authToken);
          } 
         catch(e) {
              console.log(e); 
         }
      }
    };
```